# soup find elements by classs name is not working for me

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    url = 'https://www.jobs.ch/en/vacancies/detail/10541687/?source=vacancy_search_promo'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    desc = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'text')
    
    print(len(desc))
```

> This gives me 0 length. i am trying  to **scrape** a website of job and trying to **scrape** the description div.

Comment: The web page shows ```403 Forbidden```

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored inside javascript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can use `re`/`json` modules to parse it:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.jobs.ch/en/vacancies/detail/10541687/?source=vacancy_search_promo"
data = re.search(r"__INIT__ = (\{.*\})", requests.get(url).text).group(1)

data = json.loads(data)
# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for j in data["lists"]["jobs"].values():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(j["template"], "html.parser")
    for t in soup.find_all(class_="text"):
        print(t.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n"))
```

Prints:

```
Das sollten Sie über uns wissen
MAN Energy Solutions ebnet den Weg in eine klimaneutrale Weltwirtschaft. Ob Industrieproduktion, Energie- oder maritime Wirtschaft: Wir denken ganzheitlich und packen schon heute die Herausforderungen von morgen an – für eine nachhaltige Wertschöpfung unserer Kunden. In unserem Technologieportfolio steckt die Erfahrung aus über 250 Jahren Ingenieurstradition. MAN Energy Solutions hat seinen Hauptsitz in Deutschland und beschäftigt rund 15.000 Mitarbeiter an mehr als 120 Standorten weltweit. Unsere Kunden profitieren außerdem vom globalen Service-Center-Netzwerk unserer After-Sales Marke, MAN PrimeServ.
We can offer you the following tasks
Digitization, besides decarbonization, is one of our strategic business drivers. Our growing Group Digital team is looking for a skilled
Cyber Security Engineer

...and so on.
```

Comment: You are not accepting any answer which help to solved your question. Please accept answer if it's help. See also [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).